# making a function that takes a list as input and return count of the string “bebo” in that list

Tags: python

I want a function called bebo_count that takes a list x as input and returns the count of the string “bebo” in that list.
For example, bebo_count(["bebo","buzz","bebo"]) should return 2
i have made a code like this

```
def bebo_count(x):
    for a in x:
            count = 0
            if a == "bebo":
            count += 1
    return count
```

but it doesn't work it's always return 1 to me,can any one please modify this code to be working well?!

Comment: Once you have your loop working as a learning exercise, consider the code `sum(a == "bebo" for a in x)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You keep resetting count = 0 in your loop, move it outside:

```
def bebo_count(x):
    count = 0
    for a in x:
            if a == "bebo":
            count += 1
    return count
```

Answer (score 2):

## do not reinvent the wheel :-)

There is a built in method `count`

```
x = [ "bebo", "bv", "bebo" ]
x.count("bebo")
> 2
x.count("b")
> 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `count = 0` *inside* the `for` loop. That means that at each loop iteration, irrespective of what the value of `count` was before, it gets set back to zero. You should initialize `count` outside the loop. Note also that I have corrected your indentation.

```
def bebo_count(x):
    count = 0
    for a in x:
        if a == "bebo":
            count += 1
    return count
```

For your reference, here is another way you might write this same function:

```
def bebo_count(x):
    return len([a for a in x if a == "bebo"])
```

Comment: Generally it's better to use generator expressions instead of list comprehensions if you aren't going to reuse the list. So instead of your second example with `len([a for...])`, I would recommend using `sum(1 for a in x if a == 'bebo')`, which doesn't create a throw-away list.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is: count = 0 is inside your for loop.

Answer (score 0):

To fix your code :

```
def bebo_count(x):
    count = 0 # initialize the count before you start counting
    for a in x:
        if a == "bebo":
        count += 1
    return count
```

However, a more pythonic way could be using list comprehension:

```
big_list = ["bebo", "something else", "bebo"]
def bebo_count(big_list) :
    return len( [x for x in big_list if x=="bebo" ] )

print( bebo_count(big_list))
```